# Why does the set of all singleton sets not exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proposition: For a set $X$ and its power set $P(X)$, any function $f\colon P(X)\to X$ has at least two sets $A\neq B\subseteq X$ such that $f(A)=f(B)$.

I can see how this would be true if $X$ is a finite set, since $|P(X)|\gt |X|$, so by the pigeonhole principle, at least two of the elements in $P(X)$ would have to map to the same element.

Does this proposition still hold for $X$ an infinite set? And if so, how does this show that the set of all singleton sets cannot exist?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you had a function $f\colon P(X)\to X$ such that $f(A)=f(B)\Rightarrow A=B$, then $f$ would be one-to-one, which would imply $|P(X)|\leq |X|$; since $|X|\lt |P(X)|$ holds by Cantor's Theorem, that would give you $|P(X)|\lt|P(X)|$, which is impossible. This argument does not use finiteness of $X$, so it holds for $X$ infinite as well.

Suppose that the collection of all singletons is a set $X$. Define a map $f\colon P(X)\to X$ by $f(A) = \{A\}$; this is well defined, since $\{A\}$ is a singleton. If $A\neq B$, then $\{A\}\neq\{B\}$, so $f$ would be one-to-one. Since, by the proposition, this is impossible, we conclude that our assumption that the collection of all singletons is a set must be false. Thus, there is no "set of all singletons."

Comment: Thank you, a very clear explanation. Much appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you are satisfied; doesn't have to be mine, but if you are essentially "done" here, you might want to pick one and accept it.

Answer (score 54):

If $x$ is a set containing all singletons, $\cup x$ is a set containing all sets, which leads to Russell's paradox. Thus, in $ZF$ there is no such $x$.

Comment: This, in my opinion, is the "correct" answer to the title question... no fancy functions or regularity needed. Just the union axiom and separation :)

Comment: There are a lot of ways; but the poser specifically asked how the result quoted (no injective functions $P(X)\to X$) could be used to establish that there is no set of all singletons, so presumably a direct application of the result is what was sought here.

Comment: You would have to add a proof of $\forall x \exists y (\cup x = y)$

Comment: This is the union axiom. Of course I work in ZF (or some tiny fragment).

Answer (score 7):

If you accept that the collection of all sets (denoted by $V$ usually) is not a set (but in fact a proper class) then if you look at the function $f(x) = \{ x \}$ it is 1-1 from $V$ into the sets of all singletons, thus resulting that $V$ would be a set, in contradiction to the fact that it is in fact a proper class.

But of course you'd have to accept that $V$ is a proper class as well, this is simpler and follows by the argument given in Arturo's answer (that the power-set of $V$ would be of the same cardinality).

Answer (score 3):

Your presupposition is incorrect; there are a number of set theories (some of them provably equiconsistent with ZF) in which the set of all singletons exists; see [Limiting set theory using symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/limiting-set-theory-using-symmetry/22026#22026), or Forster’s [Oxford Logic Guide](http://www.oup.com/us/catalog/general/subject/Mathematics/Logic/?view=usa&ci=9780198514770) on the subject.  (Disclaimer:  Forster discusses my work in the book, so I’m hardly unbiased, but it is the standard work.)

Comment: So if they are equiconsistent, does that mean the set of all singletons does indeed exist in ZF? I was only referring to ZF in my question.

Comment: No, “equiconsistent” just means that if ZF is consistent, so are the theories in question, e.g., Church's Set Theory with a Universal Set.  The most accessible reference is probably Forster’s article on it, http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf/church2001.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The question in the title is a consequence of the [axiom of regularity](http://books.google.com/books?id=sxr4LrgJGeAC&pg=PA53&dq=Axiom+of+regularity&hl=en&ei=lyh_TKLtJcPGswayz53lDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Axiom%20of%20regularity&f=false).
In fact If there was such a set $X$, then $\{X\}\in X$. But obviously we always have $X\in\{X\}$. Hence, we would be able to construct an infinite downward chain of sets which contradicts the  axiom of regularity.

Comment: Note however that the question in the statement also holds in ZF-{Regularity}+{Aczel's Anti-Foundation Axiom}, so Regularity is not needed.

Comment: You need to put two backslashes before a curly bracket rather than just one; otherwise, the curly bracket does not show up.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: This is really crazy :D  

I am certain I was able to TeX  curly braises a couple of days ago...or wasn't I??  Thanks!