# Using the Axiom of Regularity to show $x \in y \in x$ is impossible

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Trying to prove the claim:

$$\forall x \; \forall y \; \lnot (x \in y \in x)$$

I know we should apply the axiom of regularity to the set $\{x, y\}$.

Can anyone help?

Comment: $\{x,y\}$ is non empty: try intersecting it with its only two elements and check whether these intersections are empty or not... if none of them is, you found that this example contradicts the regularity axiom

Comment: I edited your question to improve the math formatting. If you want to see waht I did, click "edit".

Comment: See also: [Are there sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \in B$ and $B \in A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to prove a NOT statement, i.e. for all $x$ and $y$, it is NOT the case that both $x \in y$ and $y \in x$, it makes sense to proceed by contradiction. Assume -- towards a contradiction -- that we have some $x$ and $y$ such that $x \in y$ and $y \in x$.

Now, applying regularity to $\{x,y\}$, we must have that $\{x,y\}$ contains an element disjoint from itself. So either $\{x,y\}$ is disjoint from $x$, or $\{x,y\}$ is disjoint from $y$.

- **Case 1:** $\{x,y\}$ is disjoint from $x$.

  But $y \in \{x,y\}$, and $y \in x$. So they are not disjoint. Contradiction.
- **Case 2:** $\{x,y\}$ is disjoint from $y$.

  Can you do this case?

Answer (score 1):

What would be an $\in$-minimal element of $\{x, y\}$?