# Given two sets, construct disjoint set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

given two sets $A$ and $B$. How do we construct a set $C$ bijective to $B$, but disjoint to $A$?

Answer (score 1):

For example, let
$$ C=\{\,\{x,A\}\mid x\in B\,\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! The rest follows with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676121/are-there-sets-a-and-b-such-that-a-in-b-and-b-in-a