# If $a \in b$ is it possible that $b \in a$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you ever have two sets $a$ and $b$ with $a \in b \in a$? It doesn’t appear to contradict Russell’s paradox. Does it go against any ZF axioms? Feels like it might contradict regularity but I can’t seem to prove it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676121/are-there-sets-a-and-b-such-that-a-in-b-and-b-in-a

Comment: These questions solved it thanks guys