# Clarification of Proof on Elements of Set Theory Chapter $2$ Q.$8$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Currently, I am self studying Enderton's Elements of Set Theory and would like to clarify if my approach to The question in Chapter $2$ Question $8$ is valid, or  could be improved.

- **Question**

> Show that there is no set to which every singleton (that is, every set of the form $\{x\}$) belongs. [Suggestion: Show that from such a set we could construct a set to which every set belonged.]

- **Answer**

Let $A$ be the set that contains all singletons. Since there is no set to which every sets belong (Theorem $2A$), there should exist some set $x \notin \cup A$. However, this would imply that $\{x\} \notin A$, which is a contradiction. Hence, there is no such set to which every singleton belongs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your answer is fine: Since $\bigcup A$ can't contain all sets, $A$ can't contain all singletions. You could make that more explicit by  noting that, if $\{x\}\in A$ then $x\in\bigcup A$, but that's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands right now, you need to improve your argument. The theorem you are using refers to the set of all sets, not just the set of all singletons.

However, take a look at [Why does the set of all singleton sets not exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/why-does-the-set-of-all-singleton-sets-not-exist) and that might help improve your argument

Comment: Thank you for the link provided. I found that the second answer in that question used the same approach as mine, while the first answer was more tailored to the circumstances of the OP's question.

Comment: You can write this as $\exists A\, \forall x\,(\{x\}\in A)\implies$ $ \exists A\,\exists B \, (B=\cup A \land \forall x\,(\{x\}\in A)) \implies$ $\exists A\,\exists B (B=\cup A \land \forall x\,(x\in B))\implies$ $ \exists B\,\forall x\,(x\in B)$. And the last one is false so the 1st one is false.